# skip a very large cell parquet

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have a parquet file of 250 mb

One of the cell has bad data. I am assuming there is no schema issue but there is a length issue. When I skip reading this column I am able to read file via spark.
When I try to read the column then spark runs out of memory. I have tried giving 100gb ram to executor and it still fails

there are 58k rows in this file. Is there a way to recover rest of the data and ignore that 1 row / 1 cell ?

the column is named `meta` and is of type `struct<name:String,schema_version:string>`

I did try converting to json and then skip the row, but conversion to json fails

Stack trace on spark:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 10.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.3 in stage 10.0 (TID 157, ip-10-1-131-191.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 22): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 22 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits.  11.6 GB of 11.1 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead or disabling yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled because of YARN-4714.
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2041)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
```

Since we had isolated to a speciific file we tried following:

```
parquet-tools cat  /Users/gaurav/Downloads/part-00142-84bd71d5-268e-4db2-a962-193c171ed889.c000.snappy.parquet > ~/Downloads/parquue_2.json
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Parquet column dump

```
parquet-tools dump -c meta part-00142-84bd71d5-268e-4db2-a962-193c171ed889.c000.snappy.parquet 
row group 0 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

row group 1 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you provide the stack trace? I'm wondering if the executor runs out of memory or you run out of memory overhead which is used for serializing and deserializing

Comment: @Paul added stacktrace of spark and also parquet-tools

Comment: can you try `parquet-tools dump -c <your-column> <your-file>` and see if it succeeds?

Comment: @mazaneicha updated answer